# How to limit the size of an HTTP request in Java?

Tags: java, http, limit, servlet-filters

In [Express (NodeJS)](https://www.npmjs.org/package/express), you can limit the request size like this:

```
app.use(express.limit('2mb'));
```

Is there a Java equivalent? I'm using [Jersey](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey/), so any Jersey specific solution is fine, too.

After some unsuccessful research, I could only come up with two solutions:

1. Write such a filter yourself
2. Use the web server to enforce the limit. In my case, it is a Tomcat behind an Apache HTTP server.

What would you recommend? Do you know an existing library that I'm missing (to avoid writing the filter yourself)?

Comment: What's the reason for limiting the file size? If it's not really a limitation of the application, I'd lean towards server config.

Comment: Agree with @jurgemaister. Also because an user could replicate the request to the server bypassing the application's checks on the size. In that case the server would accept an unacceptable request

Comment: @jurgemaister The reason for limiting the request body is mostly to make certain denial-of-service attacks more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

You can use annotations in Jersey.

Try somethink like this:

```
@MultipartConfig(
    maxFileSize=10485760,     // 10Mb max
    fileSizeThreshold=524288, //512 Kb before buffering to disk
    maxRequestSize=10240      // 10Kb of meta data
    location=/tmp             // with permission to write, default uses tomcat tmp
)
```